# C# not able to dispose resource in catch{} statement

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, dispose

I open an excel file within my `try` block.

Then in the `catch` block, I put a statement to close that excel file as long as the excel application if any exception. I even tried `finally` and it doesn't work neither.

It appeared that there is an error message stating the variable doesn't exist in the current context.

How should I do to close the excel when exception happens?

Comment: post the code!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please post code, exact error message, link to MSDN explaining that particular error message and what exactly need explanation.

Comment: Variables declared in the `try {..}` block will not be in scope in the `catch {..}` block.  Declare the variable before the `try`.

Comment: Post some code! If your object contains `IDisposable` interface implemented, you could use it in `using(obj)` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I open an excel file within my try block.

Open the excel file immediately before your `try` block.  This will allow it to be in scope during the `catch` portion.  If you plan on always closing it, just put the logic in the `finally` block, as that will happen whether or not the exception occurs.

```
// Open file..
try
{
    // use file
}
finally
{
    // close here
}
```

Comment: Would be better declare before `try` and instance and open inside `try`? I mean, if some erro occur in the open process, it can be handled in the catch block.

Comment: @FelipeOriani Depends on your logic - it can work, but often "open" is the constructor.  If you do that, you'll need to check for null in the disposal portion.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your @ReedCopsey :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what your stating, I believe you problem is this:

```
try
{
     // Do Stuff.
}

catch
{
     // Close my connection.
}
```

That approach isn't valid, the reason is `catch` won't actually implement unless an error occurs.  So you would need to post your close in either the `try` or outside of the `try catch` portion of your code.

However you should post code, as your answer will vary on your structure, implementation, and the overall flow of your code.  As you'll to consider that C# has a automated Garbage Collection and several other variables.

You may want to think of it like an:

```
value = 3;
if (value == 0) 
{
   value = 1;
}
else if (value == 1)
{
     value = 1;
}
else
{  
     value = 5;
}
```

`value` will equal five, the reason is because `value` doesn't qualify within the other scope.  So it will fall in the `else` bracket.  Same applies for `try catch`.  Unless the `catch` is triggered with an exception your code will never enter the scope of that particular code block.